# "first I go buy" or "first I go to buy"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I'm writing a "how I make a salad" list for school and I want to say:

> "First I go buy the   ingredients...."

but I don't know if I should write;

> "First I go **to** buy the ingredients....."

Notice the difference between them as the preposition "to" is written before "buy" on the latter. Well I have my doubts because normally I would say "I go buy" not "I go to buy" as in "I've gotta go buy something" but I have to be formal and grammatical since it's for school not for a friend so I need your advice on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is not grammatically correct; "go [verb]" is short for "go to [verb]" or "go and [verb]."  The second, while there's a typo (which is obviously accidental since you spelled it right the first time), is grammatically correct.  However, I would not recommend it for several reasons:

- It's in first person; you are writing an essay about how *you* make a salad, I would write it in the imperative mood (simply "First, buy the ingredients").
- The phrase "go to [verb]" is colloquial.  This may be fine, depending upon the assignment, but if your teacher cares about that kind of thing then you might want to avoid it.
- You don't really need "go to" at all, unless you want to emphasize that you are *going somewhere* in order to buy the ingredients.  "First, I buy the ingredients" might be preferable.

Ultimately, you may want to ask your teacher as the best way to do this depends upon what your teacher wants.

Comment: Thanks ostrichofevil, thanks for the answer and for pointing out the typo. Please see as I have updated my question and removed the typo and thanks once again for the advice on how to start my essay.

Comment: I don't agree that "the first is not grammatically correct." I don't see the grammatical error in: _First I go buy the ingredients._ (I agree that your more simple form is an improvement, but I think calling the first "grammatically incorrect" is a bit of a stretch.)

Comment: @J.R. It doesn't meet correct English syntax.

Comment: By the way I have to write it in first person and my teacher said "say everything including that you go buy the ingredients". Let me update my question again to clarify that I am the one making the salad.

Comment: @ManuelHernandez - You should not be so [quick to accept an answer](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer). (Side note to ostrich - What grammatical/syntactic rule does it break?)

Comment: @J.R I think you right I should have waited for another answer I gonna take my decision back and next time I'll just wait for different opinions.

Comment: *Go* (and *come*) with a bare infinitive is perfectly acceptable in conversational American English. Safire had a [column on “go figure”](http://www.nytimes.com/1999/10/10/magazine/the-way-we-live-now-10-10-99-on-language-go-figure.html) tracing it to Yiddish speech patterns; thus *[Angela and I are going to go check out some exhibits](https://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2016/04/25/remarks-president-obama-and-chancellor-merkel)* and the saying *[go fly a kite](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/go-fly-a-kite)*.

Comment: @J.R. I tend to agree that it should be `go and` rather than just `go`. While I wouldn't bat an eyelid at it in regular speech, I'd be hesitant to say that `go buy` in this case is grammatically correct.

Comment: @choster I think the keyword here is conversational :)

Comment: @J.R. It does not violate any syntax rules that I know of, but it does not follow any either, and a valid, complete sentence must be describable using syntax rules.

Comment: @choster to elaborate upon what Rob said, since this is for school we are talking about moderately formal English and not conversational/colloquial English.  It *is* perfectly acceptable to use `go fly a kite` in conversational English, where if you care about syntax rules you might get a few funny looks, but in formal English, not so much.

Comment: @ostrich - I like how you worded your comment in that last remark to choster; I think that presents a more balanced picture. I also think [this is an interesting ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go+buy+the%2Cgo+to+buy+the%2Cgo+and+buy+the&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), although I must add that a large number of those hits for `go buy the` are found inside quotation marks in works of fiction; that is, they are emulating conversation speech rather than formal English.