# What's the difference between "go meet" and "go to meet"?

Tags: word-difference

Reading the book on which I'm learning English, I've come across a weird (for me) omitting the "to" in sentence: "I'd better **go meet** with him then."

Say, if it were "I'd better **go to meet** with him then.", would there be any difference between the two sentences? When I should prefer using one instead the other?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English. If I made a mistake somewhere, please correct me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["first I go buy" or "first I go to buy"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88515/first-i-go-buy-or-first-i-go-to-buy)

Comment: @JBH That question and its accepted answer are not helpful here, because there, the recommendation is to avoid "go" altogether, because it's normally not used in phrasing for recipes.

Comment: Folks I would avoid using questions with no up-voted answers as targets for duplicates. The goal here is to direct the author of this question to a good answer, not to consolidate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I can say is that it's very common in everyday, colloquial English to drop that *to* when a verb follows these two very specific verbs: *to go* and *to come*. For example:

> I'm gonna **go find** something to eat.
>
> The next time you're in town, I hope you'll **come see** me.

I can't explain why this happens, but you will see native English speakers say that all the time. No one is ever going to say *I'm gonna go to find something to eat.* That just doesn't sound as smooth. Though, while possible, you're less likely to hear *I hope you'll come to see me* than *I hope you'll come see me*. I would recommend that you pay particular attention to how people say things when next time you hear somebody use the verbs *to go* or *to come* in their sentence.

Comment: Worth pointing out that “go... do [something]” is non-standard English. It is used as slang in American English, and *entirely incorrect* in British English. Correctly, it should either be “Go *and* do [something]”, or “go *to* do [something]”. It’s the same with “come”.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that "go meet" is American English.

From experience, I would say "I want to go and meet Virginia" etc..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).